# Vimwiki bullet point wrapping creates a new line

Tags: neovim, wrapping, plugin-vimwiki

When I use vimwiki and I write past the `text` width, the bullet point will wrap. This is what I expect. However, the wrap will be a new line:

```markdown
1. something to say .....
   a second line wrapped after 80 textwidth.        < -- this is a new line
```

Current settings in my init.lua:

```
local set = vim.opt

set.wrap = true
set.linebreak = true
set.textwidth = 80
```

I also have `set formatoptions+=r` and `set formatoptions-=t` in my init.vim

I want the second line to wrap but be on the same vim line.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want hard wrap (Vim creating new lines to wrap text) you have to set `textwidth` to 0:

```lua
set.textwidth = 0
```

Comment: I tried that, but then the line goes to the end of the page. Visually I like the wrapping. Is there a way to have it visually but not actually?

Comment: I don't think so. The approved [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/989317/329318) make me think it is not possible.

Comment: What about `tw=0` and `wrap`? That doesn't hard wrap but does give visual wrapping at the end of the window (and you can control the appearance through other options) @Vinn